# Oracle OCI jdbc driver traps ORA-01403: no data found

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle-call-interface

I'm having a problem with the Oracle OCI jdbc driver not throwing ORA-01403 No data found exceptions.  Relevant to Oracle 11 and 12.  Maybe there is a property or something I need to set on the Connection object.  The thin driver properly throws an exception, but the OCI driver just continues on with no error and updates 0 rows even though there is data in the table.

The output of the following program is:

Exception thrown from THIN Driver: ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "EE.TABLEX_UPSERT_PRE", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EE.TABLEX_UPSERT_PRE'

rows updated from OCI Driver =0

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Driver d = (Driver) Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance();
        Properties info = new Properties();
        info.put("user", "me");
        info.put("password", "mypwd");

        Connection thinConnection = d.connect("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:DEV",info);
        Connection ociConnection = d.connect("jdbc:oracle:oci:@DEV",info);

        try {
            Statement s = thinConnection.createStatement();
            s.execute("UPDATE tablex SET name='newname'");
            System.out.println("rows updated in THIN Driver =" + s.getUpdateCount());
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception thrown from THIN Driver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            Statement s = ociConnection.createStatement();
            s.execute("UPDATE tablex SET name='newname'");
            System.out.println("rows updated from OCI Driver =" + s.getUpdateCount());
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception thrown from OCI Driver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(0);
}

{////// SQL
CREATE TABLE TABLEX 
(
  NAME VARCHAR2(20) 
);

INSERT INTO TABLEX(name) values('data1');


CREATE TABLE TABLEy
(
  ID NUMBER 
);



create or replace 
TRIGGER TABLEX_UPSERT_PRE 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON TABLEX FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
cid number;
BEGIN 
select id into cid from tabley where id=0; -- INTENTIONAL No Data Found error
end;
}
```

Comment: Please note there is no `ORA-01403: no data found` for the `UPDATE` statement. You have a trigger attached to the table where the exception is triggered, probably by trying to select non existing data. You must investigate the *trigger* to see the problem.

Comment: You are correct, the trigger has code which is causing the no data found error.  That is intentional, to illustrate that the exception is not being thrown back to Java when I'm using the OCI driver the way that it is when I'm using the Thin JDBC driver.  The OCI driver is just eating the exception.

Comment: Please post the relevant DDL of the table and trigger in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: As a followup I've added the SQL needed to completely re-create the issue.  Also, NO_DATA_FOUND is the only exception defined with a non-negative result code, and coincidentally is the only Oracle Exception which the OCI driver doesn't seem to work with.

Comment: NO_DATA_FOUND exception;
    pragma EXCEPTION_INIT(NO_DATA_FOUND, 100);